# How to ignore rules in StandardJS/ESLint?

Tags: javascript, gulp, eslint, lint, standardjs

I'm trying to ignore certain rules in [StandardJS](https://standardjs.com/), but I can't get it to work, when using [gulp-standard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-standard).

Do I have to write the exceptions inside a JavaScript file? I would like to just specify what to ignore in my package file.

Is that possible? How can I do it in my gulpfile?

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
  return gulp.src(jsWatchPath)
  .pipe(standard())
  .pipe(standard.reporter('default', {
    breakOnError: true,
    quiet: true,
    showRuleNames: true,
    showFilePath: false
  }))
});
```

Comment: Anyone? Seems i cant get this right.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you checked the source, how the gulp plugin uses StandardJS?

Answer (score 1):

The [**gulp-standard**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-standard) package uses [**StandardJS's Node.js API**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard#is-there-a-nodejs-api). Pass your options as an Object using the documentation.

Otherwise, create a file called **.eslintrc** in your project's root directory with your own [**ESLint configurations**](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html) *(StandardJS uses ESLint under the hood)*.

Comment: Yes, standardjs uses eslint under the hood, but AFAICT it ignores eslint configuration files.